# How to store summary function into a vector then for loop in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, for-loop, summary

I have the following dataset. For each month and site, I'm trying to use a particular package (EcoSim) to estimate overlap (RA4Model).

I want to achieve two things:

```
install.packages("EcoSimR")
library(EcoSimR)
set.seed(111)
month <- rep(c("J","J","J","F"), each = 4)
site <- rep(c("1","2","3","1"), each = 4)
species <- rep(c("A","B","C","D"), rep = 4)
q1 <- rnorm(16,5,1)
q2 <- rnorm(16,5,1)
q3 <- rnorm(16,5,1)
q4 <- rnorm(16,5,1)
q5 <- rnorm(16,5,1)

df <- data.frame(month, site, species,q1,q2,q3,q4,q5)
df.site <- df[df$month == "J" & df$site == "1",]
df.site <- df.site[,-c(1,2,3)]

RA4model <- niche_null_model(speciesData=df.site, 
                             algo="ra4", metric="pianka", 
                             suppressProg=TRUE,nReps=5000)

summary(RA4model)
```

First, I want to store certain values from the summary into the corresponding rows in R
Here is the output of summary(RA4Model) for Month "J" and site "1"

```
# Time Stamp:  Sun Jan  8 11:43:05 2023 
# Reproducible:  FALSE 
# Number of Replications:  5000 
# Elapsed Time:  1 secs 
# Metric:  pianka 
# Algorithm:  ra4 
# Observed Index:  0.96516 
# Mean Of Simulated Index:  0.95101 
# Variance Of Simulated Index:  9.4906e-05 
# Lower 95% (1-tail):  0.93823 
# Upper 95% (1-tail):  0.96979 
# Lower 95% (2-tail):  0.93729 
# Upper 95% (2-tail):  0.97272 
# Lower-tail P =  0.8982 
# Upper-tail P =  0.1018 
# Observed metric > 4491 simulated metrics 
# Observed metric < 509 simulated metrics 
# Observed metric = 0 simulated metrics 
# Standardized Effect Size (SES):  1.453
```

Storing this output into vector. I don't know how to store the lower-1tailP and SES from the summary output into the dataset

```
df.out <- df[,c(1,2,3)]
df.out$Obs <- RA4model$Obs
df.out$Sim <- mean(RA4model$Sim)
df.out$lower-1tailP <-  #This should be 0.93
df.out$SES <-  #This should be 1.453
```

Next, I want to loop this so that it does it for each unique(month,site). So the final dataframe looks something like this:

```
month site Obs Sim lower-1tailP SES
  J     1   ..  ..   ..          ..
  J     2   ..   ..  ..          ..
  J     3   ..   ..  ..          ..
  F     1   ..   ..  ..          ..
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a helper function `get_eco_sim_result()`, which returns a list of the parameters of interest:

```
get_eco_sim_result <- function(spd, algo= "ra4", metric = "pianka", nReps=500) {
  model = niche_null_model(speciesData = spd,
    algo = algo,metric =metric, nReps = nReps, suppressProg = TRUE
  )
  return(list(
    Obs = model$Obs,
    Sim = mean(model$Sim),
    lower_1tailp = quantile(model$Sim,0.05),
    SES = (model$Obs - mean(model$Sim))/sd(model$Sim)
  ))
}
```

Then use `lapply()` to apply that helper function to each subset of the data; here I obtain the subsets of the data using `split()`. By wrapping the retuned list in `data.frame()`, you can subsequently use `do.call()` with `rbind()`

```
do.call(
  rbind, lapply(split(df, list(month,site), drop=T), \(d) {
    data.frame(get_eco_sim_result(d[,-c(1,2,3)], nReps=5000))
  })
)
```

Output:

```
          Obs       Sim lower_1tailp       SES
F.1 0.9641760 0.9546306    0.9429722 1.0966176
J.1 0.9651613 0.9508969    0.9381335 1.4635265
J.2 0.9931026 0.9842322    0.9800247 2.9524328
J.3 0.9726413 0.9674799    0.9586858 0.7669562
```

Your original question, however, is perhaps less about the helper function and the loop, but rather about how the parameters in `summary(RA4model)` are estimated?  Use `getAnywhere(summary.nichenullmod)` to see how these are estimated.