# How to set na.rm = TRUE when being used from a R package (EcoSimR)?

Tags: r, package, mean, na

For each month and site, I'm trying to use a particular package (EcoSim) to estimate overlap (RA4Model) [as described in this example.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75050841/how-to-store-summary-function-into-a-vector-then-for-loop-in-r) . However, I find that whenever all the columns for a given row are 0, the loop breaks down with the error that na.rm is FALSE. I am not sure how/ where I can set na.rm = TRUE in the return loop. Any suggestions?

```
#install.packages("EcoSimR")
library(EcoSimR)

set.seed(111)
month <- rep(c("J","J","J","F"), each = 4)
site <- rep(c("1","2","3","1"), each = 4)
species <- rep(c("A","B","C","D"), rep = 4)
q1 <- rtruncnorm(n=14, a=0, b=10, mean=0, sd=1))
q2 <- rtruncnorm(n=16, a=0, b=10, mean=1, sd=1)
q3 <- rtruncnorm(n=16, a=0, b=10, mean=0, sd=1)
q4 <- rtruncnorm(n=16, a=0, b=10, mean=1, sd=1)
q5 <- rtruncnorm(n=16, a=0, b=10, mean=1, sd=1)

df <- data.frame(month, site, species,q1,q2,q3,q4,q5)
df[1,c(4:8)] <- 0
df[6,c(4:8)] <- 0
df[15,c(4:8)] <- 0

get_eco_sim_result <- function(spd, algo= "ra4", metric = "pianka", nReps=500) {
  model = niche_null_model(speciesData = spd,
                           algo = algo,metric =metric, nReps = nReps, suppressProg = TRUE
  )
  return(list(
    Obs = model$Obs,
    Sim = mean(model$Sim, na.rm = TRUE),
    lower_1tailp = quantile(model$Sim,0.05),
    SES = (model$Obs - mean(model$Sim))/sd(model$Sim)
  ))
}

output <- do.call(
  rbind, lapply(split(df, list(month,site), drop=T), \(d) {
    data.frame(get_eco_sim_result(d[,-c(1,2,3)], nReps=5000))
  })
)

output
```

When there are zeros in the model, it throws out an error

```
Error: Error in quantile.default(model$Sim, 0.05) : 
  missing values and NaN's not allowed if 'na.rm' is FALSE
```

Comment: try ```lower_1tailp = quantile(model$Sim,0.05,na.rm=TRUE)```

Comment: @peter861222 Still gives me only NANs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the rows of `0` you're inserting.  First, let's generate your data.

```r
library(EcoSimR)
#> Loading required package: MASS
library(truncnorm)
set.seed(111)
month <- rep(c("J","J","J","F"), each = 4)
site <- rep(c("1","2","3","1"), each = 4)
species <- rep(c("A","B","C","D"), rep = 4)
q1 <- rtruncnorm(n=16, a=0, b=10, mean=0, sd=1)
q2 <- rtruncnorm(n=16, a=0, b=10, mean=1, sd=1)
q3 <- rtruncnorm(n=16, a=0, b=10, mean=0, sd=1)
q4 <- rtruncnorm(n=16, a=0, b=10, mean=1, sd=1)
q5 <- rtruncnorm(n=16, a=0, b=10, mean=1, sd=1)

df <- data.frame(month, site, species,q1,q2,q3,q4,q5)
df[1,c(4:8)] <- 0
df[6,c(4:8)] <- 0
df[15,c(4:8)] <- 0
```

The `niche_null_model()` function ultimately calls the function you specify in `metric`.  In your case, the function calls `pianka()`, the code for which is below:

```r
pianka
#> function (m = matrix(rpois(80, 1), nrow = 10)) 
#> {
#>     m <- m/rowSums(m)
#>     pairwise <- cbind(t(combn(nrow(m), 2)), 0)
#>     for (i in 1:nrow(pairwise)) pairwise[i, 3] <- sum(m[pairwise[i, 
#>         1], ] * m[pairwise[i, 2], ])/sqrt(sum(m[pairwise[i, 1], 
#>         ]^2) * sum(m[pairwise[i, 2], ]^2))
#>     return(mean(pairwise[, 3]))
#> }
#> <bytecode: 0x7fcb17961700>
#> <environment: namespace:EcoSimR>
```

Note, that the first line of code is normalizing the matrix `m` so that it sums to 1 in each row.  When you have a row of all `0`, dividing each `0` by the row sum produces a row of `NaN`.

```r
s <- split(df, list(month,site), drop=T)
m <- s[[1]][,-(1:3)]
m/rowSums(m)
#>            q1         q2        q3        q4        q5
#> 13 0.03100336 0.19049927 0.1672990 0.1953235 0.4158749
#> 14 0.58478135 0.06378461 0.1619580 0.1256290 0.0638470
#> 15        NaN        NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
#> 16 0.04609515 0.38693966 0.1419413 0.2213337 0.2036902
```

Since the code for `pianka()` includes a bunch of pairwise comparisons, any comparison involving one of the `NaN` will evaluate to `NaN`.  Here's what the pairwise comparisons that `pianka()` produces looks like for the first subset data frame that you pass in:

```
s <- split(df, list(month,site), drop=T)
m <- s[[1]][,-(1:3)]
m <- m/rowSums(m)
pairwise <- cbind(t(combn(nrow(m), 2)), 0)
for (i in 1:nrow(pairwise)) pairwise[i, 3] <- sum(
  m[pairwise[I, 1], ] * 
  m[pairwise[i, 2], ])/
  sqrt(sum(m[pairwise[i, 1], ]^2) * 
  sum(m[pairwise[i, 2], ]^2))

pairwise
#>      [,1] [,2]      [,3]
#> [1,]    1    2 0.3295038
#> [2,]    1    3       NaN
#> [3,]    1    4 0.8422317
#> [4,]    2    3       NaN
#> [5,]    2    4 0.3598199
#> [6,]    3    4       NaN
```

Note that three of the pairwise comparison values are `NaN`.  The returned result of the `pianka()` function is the mean of column 3 of the `pairwise` matrix.  Since that contains `NaN` values, the mean evaluates to `NaN`.  Note how you get a result for the fourth subset data frame that is not `NaN` because the matrix doesn't have a row of zeros.

```r
pianka(s[[4]][,-(1:3)])
#> [1] 0.7784348
```

So, the problem is that by including a row of all zeros, you're causing all of the simulated values to be `NaN` which produces a quantile value of `NaN` regardless of whether or not `na.rm=TRUE` is specified as an argument to `quantile()`.